# Url Redirect htaccess with two query string

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I have a query string like this:

```
product_details.php?id=17&name=dhruba
```

How do I change this to:

```
product_details/dhruba
```

Please explain me how to redirect id with title from database. I'm doing all my calculation using the id.

Comment: this is a very simple task. Just look up MVC and pretty URLs and you will find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a mod_rewrite rule in an .htaccess file, it should look something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^product_details/(.*)$ product_details.php?name=$1
RewriteBase /
```

Although if you also require the ID I would recommend passing that as a parameter to the rewrite rule.

Comment: how to do that, please explain??

Comment: Create a file named .htaccess and place it in the root directory of your website. Paste the contents of my comment above and then attempt to view the /product_details/dhruba/ link to see if it is redirecting properly.